# How to return more attribute from CAS server to CAS Client use LDAP account

Tags: cas

How to return more attribute from CAS server to CAS Client, I use LDAP account to login, follow this guide https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/attributes but it just return username. (CAS v3.5.2). I think have some wrong config in deployerConfigContext.xml. Can you give me correct deployerConfigContext.xml file or a correct guide to solve problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can find more info from link https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/integration/Attribute-Release.html